# Create HTML wizard of Eclipse Plugin for GWT does not work

Tags: html, eclipse, gwt, new-operator

I can't create HTML files with a wizard of Eclipse Plugin for GWT.

When opening "New HTML Page" window and filling it with data, the Finish button does nothing. Neither window closed nor HTML file created.

I can create HTML file manually and it works. Generally GWT degigning and debugging under Eclipse works.

Eclipse version is

Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

GWT version is

2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6338